# Strange error in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I'm currently working on an MS SharePoint project, and all I added is an CSS file, which isn't the cause of my error.

The sharepoint version is 2010.

O already tried to disable the customised css, but that didn't resolve the problem.

On some times, when i load the homepage and try to click the edit symbol or tab, i get the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PageState' of undefined sp.ribbon.js:2

Help anyone, I can't figure out whats happening there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which browser you are using? SharePoint 2010 UI is not 100% compatible with Chrome

Comment: yup, i know.. but the error is in internet explorer ass well

Comment: Just wanted to add my 2 cents.  The latest version of Chrome is having a lot of problems with Sharepoint 2010.  When i put my custom webpart on the page the Site Actions/Edit no longer works.  This isn't a problem with Firefox/IE and wasn't a problem with before chrome.  Currently have chrome 22.0.1229.96 m.  I received the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the use of an external tool like Fiddler to see how the CSS file is performing first  - [Using Fiddler to Streamline SharePoint CSS Design](http://www.mpspartners.com/2012/02/UsingFiddlertoStreamlineSharePointCSSDesign/)

Answer (score 0):

How are you adding the css file?  If you modified the master page to  reference the css file, I'd suspect there is a syntax error in the master page.  Restore your backed-up master page(always back up files you modify in SPD), then see if the error goes away.